# Output is not what it should be

Tags: c++, memory

So there is a program that I am working on, that requires me to access data from a char array containing hex values. I have to use a function called func(), in this example, in order to do access the data structure. Func() contains 3 pointer variables, each of different types, and I can use any of them to access the data in the array. Whichever datatype I choose will affect what values will be stored to the pointer. Soo heres the code:

```
unsigned char data[]
{
    0xBA, 0xDA, 0x69, 0x50,
    0x33, 0xFF, 0x33, 0x40,
    0x20, 0x10, 0x03, 0x30,
    0x66, 0x03, 0x33, 0x40,
}

func()
{
   unsigned char *ch;
   unsigned int i*;
   unsigned short* s;
   unsigned int v;  

   s = (unsigned short*)&data[0];
   v = s[6];
   printf("val:0x%x \n",v);
}
```

Output:

> Val:0x366

The problem with this output is that it should be 0x0366 with the zero in front of the 3, but it gets cut off at the printf statement, and I'm not allowed to modify that. How else could I fix this?

Comment: Why can't you modify the `printf` statement?

Comment: 0x366 and 0x0366 are the same number. So your output is correct. If you are not allowed to modify the printf statement then there is absolutely nothing you can do about it.

Comment: No not in the actual code, the code above is for illustration

Comment: @Rouke its always best to post actual code, otherwise you get people correcting the mistakes you've made in your pretend code. Or even worse, not knowing about the mistakes that are in your real code, but not in your pretend code.

Comment: Thanks for asking that, that's crucial detail.

Comment: Also, you have marked c++ and are using printf which primarily originated from c. Are you allowed to use c++ and cout instead :) just curious?

Comment: No I can't, but I'm curious as to how hex formatting using cout would work. I could search, but sometimes it's faster to get answers here :D

Comment: @Rouke From memory `cout << "0x" << hex << setfill('0') << setw(4) << v;` and even that verbose mess is worse than `printf` because it has a side effect on the stream state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a format that specifies leading zeros: `%04x`.

Without changing the format passed to `printf` or replacing it entirely I'm afraid there's no way to affect the output.

Comment: Sorry, speaking for the OP here but, 'I am not allowed to modify the printf statement'

Comment: @john, this is *the* answer. Stupid requirements on the part of the OP does not change that.

Comment: Yes, I've known of this solution, but thanks. This can help other people.

Comment: But out of curioisty, why did the printf cut the 0 out? Printf would not do the same if the number was 1 or any positive integer. For example, if s[1] was assigned to v, then output would be 0x5069.

Comment: @Rouke because the `0` doesn't mean anything in this context. `1` would fefinitely mean something so cutting it would change the answer.

Comment: @Rouke because removing leading zeros does not change the value of a number, but removing any other digit does.

Comment: @Rouke it removes zeroes that have no meaning. Like you could say 0x1 = 0x01 = 0x000000000000000001 whatever, it's all the same number, so how could `printf` know how many insignificant zeroes you want if you haven't told it?